# I can't create many users in script nextcloud

Tags: shell, nextcloud

I am faced with the problem of mass creation of users in nextcloud.

I use ubuntu server, nginx, postgresql.

Using oc commands, I create users in nextcloud.
Here is the code:

```
for user in "${LINES[@]}"; do
    username=$(echo $user | cut -d: -f1)
    password=$(echo $user | cut -d: -f2)
    echo "Имя:"
    echo "$username"
    echo "Пароль:"
    echo "$password"
    echo "Конец итерации"

    export OC_PASS=$(echo $user | cut -d: -f2)
    echo "Пароль - GLOBAL:"
    echo "$OC_PASS"

    su -s /bin/sh www-data -c "php $OCC user:add --display-name="$username" --password-from-env --group="$GROUP" $username"
done
```

As you can see, the global environment variable OC_PASS is declared in the iteration.
The problem is that after executing the code, I can't get in by login and password, it gives an error

But if you take out the declaration of the OC_PASS variable from the iteration, then everything works correctly. What could be the problem?

I'm trying to create a script for many users in NextCloud at once.

Comment: Have a try using an echo for a test to echo out the password from the environment instead of firing the occ command.

Comment: But one thought apart from the immediate issue you face: is it really a good idea to mass create user accounts directly in nextcloud? Especially using a plain text password, wherever that comes from? That certainly is not how user credentials should get handled today. Have you explored the usage of a background authority for nextcloud instead, something like an LDAP server or wherever those users already have an account?